# TypeScript string-based enum compiler error

Tags: enums, typescript

I want to create a string-based enum to represent Currencies in my system (USD, GBP, EUR, etc - such strings as the only allowed values).

I found exactly what I need in [Basarat's TypeScript book](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/stringLiteralType.html). The thing is, when I try to use it as-is:

```
type CardinalDirection =
    "North"
    | "East"
    | "South"
    | "West";
```

I get a compiler error:

```
myfile.ts(4,5): error TS1110: Type expected.
```

I'm using tsc `Version 1.5.0-beta`. The question is: which versions do support this feature and/or how can I make it work?

---

edit: after upgrading tsc to 1.8.9 I get the same error.

Comment: The following TypeScript example works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/y8yz1hcm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String literal types were added in [TypeScript 1.8](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/02/22/announcing-typescript-1-8-2/).

Your code works fine in the TypeScript [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=type%20CardinalDirection%20%3D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22North%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20%22East%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20%22South%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7C%20%22West%22%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0Alet%20dir%3A%20CardinalDirection%20%3D%20%22North%22%3B), so the syntax looks fine.

Comment: forgot that my `grunt-typescript` plugin for grunt is using a lot older version of `typescript` :(